# Adventure or urban exploration between Belgrade and Budapest

Tags: adventure, croatia, central-europe, serbia, hungary

I have 3 days to get from Belgrade to Budapest, and I'd really like to do some adventuring in that time. I was originally going to see the abandoned Olympic ruins in Sarajevo, but the travel time from Sarajevo back to Budapest is too long. Does anyone have suggestions for what to see along my trip back? I could travel by air, train, or car, but I want to spend less than $250 on the arrangements. My interests are in urban exploration and abandoned buildings, but I would settle for anything adventurous and unique. I have a US passport and international driver's license, so I shouldn't have a problem getting through any neighboring countries.

Comment: It sucks you're abandoning the option, Sarajevo is very nice, it's a very rich urban environment. I personally was impressed by the multicultural city, plus the big historic part. And there is a train leaving from Sarajevo in the morning and arriving in the evening in Budapest. It's long, but the distance is quite important anyway.

Comment: I know - I tried renting a car, but they wanted to charge a $350 EUR dropoff fee to pick up in Belgrade / Sarajevo and dropoff in budapest! In addition to regular fees. One option might be to rent a car in Belgrade, drive to Sarajevo, then drive back at night and take a night train back to Budapest.

Answer (score 10):

On the train line between Belgrade and Budapest are at least two interesting cities, [Novi Sad](http://wikitravel.org/en/Novi_Sad) and [Subotica](http://wikitravel.org/en/Subotica). I think there are both worth visiting even though I don't remember too many abandoned buildings (wasn't looking for them). You get quite a few of them in Belgrade.

Over all on the Balkans, I've seen most damage from the wars in Bosnia-Herzogovina, the [sniper-tower](http://gottakeepmovin.com/2011/11/09/banking-destruction-the-mostar-sniper-tower/) in Mostar comes to mind.

A great abandoned building in South Eastern Europe is [Buzludzha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzludzha) in Bulgaria, but that's too far off-route for you.

Comment: Novi Sad + Subotica. That's an excellent recommendation

Comment: Wow - Buzludzha looks amazing - this is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for - just a bit too far off my path to see, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Not usual place to visit, but this is my favorite. City called Kikinda
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikinda

You can get there by train or bus from Belgrade or Subotica, so it is on your way. I alway rent car, so it's easy and fun. Ypu can make day trips with rent car from Novi Sad too.

My favorite place is abandon factory that is not artist colony
http://terra.rs/en/
great place to visit, great people, contact them before you go to check current events

In National Museum of Kikinda you can see some mammoth skeleton and near by is big hotel Narvik, that I heard is recently closed as gone broke. not sure can you visit it, mayeb ask people in Terra colony.

When in Belgrade, wonder around Kalemegdan, it wonderful place to be.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I went [caving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell%C3%A9rt_Hill_Cave) when near Budapest. Super scary but amazing experience. (I should point out I am slightly claustrophobic!)

Comment: Thanks - do you have any info about the caves you visited?

Comment: http://www.budapest.com/city_guide/sights/caves/palvolgyi_cave.en.html